# An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source - Problem when using Dispatcher.Invoke()

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher, itemscontrol

I'm writing a `WPF` application (`MVVM` pattern using `MVVM Light Toolkit`) to read and display a bunch of internal log files my company uses. The goal is to read from multiple files, extract content from each line, put them in a class object and add the said object to an `ObservableCollection`. I've set the `ItemsSource` of a `DataGrid` on my `GUI` to this list so it displays the data in neat rows and columns. I have a `ProgressBar` control in a second window, which during the file read and display process will update the progress.

### Setup

Note that all these methods are stripped down to the essentials removing all the irrelevant code bits.

**Load Button**

When the user selects the directory which contains log files and clicks this button, the process begins. I open up the window that contains the `ProgressBar` at this point. I use a `BackgroundWorker` for this process.

```
public void LoadButtonClicked()
{
    _dialogService = new DialogService();
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker
    {
        WorkerReportsProgress = true
    };
    worker.DoWork += ProcessFiles;
    worker.ProgressChanged += Worker_ProgressChanged;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

**ProcessFiles() Method**

This reads **all** files in the directory selected, and processes them one by one. Here, when launching the progress bar window, I'm using `Dispatcher.Invoke()`.

```
private void ProcessFiles(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    LogLineList = new ObservableCollection<LogLine>();

    System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        _dialogService.ShowProgressBarDialog();
    });

    var fileCount = 0;
    foreach (string file in FileList)
    {
        fileCount++;
        int currProgress = Convert.ToInt32(fileCount / (double)FileList.Length * 100);
        ProcessOneFile(file);
        (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(currProgress);
    }
}
```

**ProcessOneFile() Method**

This, as the name suggests, reads one file, go through line-by-line, converts the content to my class objects and adds them to the list.

```
public void ProcessOneFile(string fileName)
{
    if (FileIO.OpenAndReadAllLinesInFile(fileName, out List<string> strLineList))
    {
        foreach (string line in strLineList)
        {
            if (CreateLogLine(line, out LogLine logLine))
            {
                if (logLine.IsRobotLog)
                {
                    LogLineList.Add(logLine);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So this works just fine, and displays my logs as I want them.

### Problem

However, *after* displaying them, if I scroll my `DataGrid`, the `GUI` hangs and gives me the following exception.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'An ItemsControl is inconsistent
>   with its items source.   See the inner exception for more
>   information.'

After reading about this on SO and with the help of Google I have figured out that this is because my `LogLineList` being inconsistent with the `ItemsSource` which results in a conflict.

**Current Solution**

I found out that if I put the line of code in `ProcessOneFile` where I add a class object to my list inside a second `Dispatcher.Invoke()` it solves my problem. Like so:

```
if (logLine.IsRobotLog)
{
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        LogLineList.Add(logLine);
    });                                
}
```

Now this again works fine, but the problem is this terribly slows down the processing time. Whereas previously a log file with 10,000 lines took about 1s, now it's taking maybe 5-10 times as longer.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this to be expected? Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: If you can batch updates instead of real time, then create a seperate collection(non-obs) and add loglines to that, every 5 seconds - change the item source to a new obs collection created from the non-obs collection

Comment: The LoadButtonClick method is located in the View code behind?

Comment: @shat90 I will give it a try and see if it's feasible.

Comment: @SirRufo, no, I'm using `MVVM` so it's in the main window's `ViewModel`. That method is attached to the click event of the button.

Comment: @Sach Well, then you should define an ICommand property in the ViewModel and bind that to the Command property of the button. Method assignment is not the right MVVM way of binding. Just FYI

Comment: @SirRufo yeah that is what I've done, maybe I didn't make myself clear. I'm using `MVVM Light Toolkit`s `RelayCommand` for that.

Comment: @Sach check out a [sample application on github](https://github.com/SirRufo/so/tree/master/52614428/WPFAsyncProcess) to have a starting point. I am using ReactiveUI but that should not matter at all - just another MVVM helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well observable collection is not thread safe.  So it works the second way because all work is being done on the UI thread via dispatcher.

You can use asynchronous operations to make this type of flow easier.  By awaiting for the results and updating the collection\progress on the result, you will keep your UI responsive and code clean.

If you cant or don't want to use asynchronous operations, batch the updates to the collection and do the update on the UI thread.

Edit
Something like this as an example

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //dir contents
    var files = new string[4] { "file1", "file2", "file3", "file4" };
    //progress bar for each file
    Pg.Value = 0;
    Pg.Maximum = files.Length;
    foreach(var file in files)
    {                
        await ProcessOneFile(file, entries => 
        {
            foreach(var entry in entries)
            {
                LogEntries.Add(entry);
            }
        });
        Pg.Value++;
    }
}

public async Task ProcessOneFile(string fileName, Action<List<string>> onEntryBatch)
{
    //Get the lines
    var lines = await Task.Run(() => GetRandom());
    //the max amount of lines you want to update at once
    var batchBuffer = new List<string>(100);

    //Process lines
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        //Create the line
        if (CreateLogLine(line, out object logLine))
        {
            //do your check
            if (logLine != null)
            {
                //add
                batchBuffer.Add($"{fileName} -{logLine.ToString()}");
                //check if we need to flush
                if (batchBuffer.Count != batchBuffer.Capacity)
                    continue;
                //update\flush
                onEntryBatch(batchBuffer);
                //clear 
                batchBuffer.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    //One last flush
    if(batchBuffer.Count > 0)
        onEntryBatch(batchBuffer);            
}
```

Comment: _By awaiting for the results and updating the collection\progress on the result, you will keep your UI responsive and code clean._ So do you mean I should `await` the `CreateLogLine()` method and update the collection?

Comment: More along the lines you want to await the process file and use an action callback to update off the collection in batches.  I updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
public object SyncLock = new object();
```

In your constructor:

```
BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(LogLineList, SyncLock);
```

Then in your function:

```
if (logLine.IsRobotLog)
{
    lock(SyncLock)
    {
        LogLineList.Add(logLine);
    }                               
}
```

This will keep the collection synchronized in which ever thread you update it from.

Comment: This did not help. I still have the problem.

Comment: Do you mean the speed problem or the sync problem? As far as speed, did you try moving the lock outside of the loop?

Comment: Not the speed problem, it still continues to hang after loading whenever I try to scroll (or any operation such as maximizing the window which causes to redraw the `DataGrid`).